# Internal Server Error (500) Shopify app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify, internal-server-error

I followed a tutorial to build an app that displays all the products and some of its details. I have managed to successfully do this part. the problem is that when I click on a link to show the description of the product on another page, it gives a (500) internal server error

Here is the code:

home_controller.rb:

```
class HomeController < ShopifyApp::AuthenticatedController

  def index
    @products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, params: { limit: 10 })
  end

  def show
    @products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

index.html.erb:

```
<% content_for :javascript do %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    ShopifyApp.ready(function(){
      ShopifyApp.Bar.initialize({
        title: "Home",
        icon: "<%= asset_path('favicon.ico') %>"
      });
    });
  </script>
<% end %>

<h2>Products</h2>

<ul>
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <p>
      <b><%= product.title %><br></b>
      ID: <%= product.id %><br>
      Vendor: <%= product.vendor %><br>
      Created at: <%= product.created_at %><br>
    </p>
    <li><%= link_to 'Show description', home_show_path(product) %></li>
    <br><br>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

show.html.erb:

```
<h1><%= @product.title %></h1>
<p>Description: <%= @product.body_html %></p>
```

heroku logs:

```
2016-12-28T01:01:25.028806+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-12-28T01:01:25.028728 #4]  INFO -- : [6a2e2c9e-b81e-4ad4-91fc-465c54f339f4] Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2016-12-28T01:01:25.028921+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-12-28T01:01:25.028865 #4]  INFO -- : [6a2e2c9e-b81e-4ad4-91fc-465c54f339f4]   Parameters: {"hmac"=>"df343ac1be8d47fc346c85012e46870a3d1d2c7d593259d6a7e5e2e4be2a60d6", "protocol"=>"https://", "shop"=>"gels-store.myshopify.com", "timestamp"=>"1482886883"}
2016-12-28T01:01:25.099398+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2016-12-28T01:01:25.099299 #4] DEBUG -- : [6a2e2c9e-b81e-4ad4-91fc-465c54f339f4]   Shop Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2016-12-28T01:01:25.550140+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-12-28T01:01:25.550053 #4]  INFO -- : [6a2e2c9e-b81e-4ad4-91fc-465c54f339f4]   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/embedded_app (7.2ms)
2016-12-28T01:01:25.542213+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-12-28T01:01:25.542094 #4]  INFO -- : [6a2e2c9e-b81e-4ad4-91fc-465c54f339f4]   Rendering home/index.html.erb within layouts/embedded_app
2016-12-28T01:01:25.553973+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-12-28T01:01:25.553914 #4]  INFO -- : [6a2e2c9e-b81e-4ad4-91fc-465c54f339f4]   Rendered layouts/_flash_messages.html.erb (0.8ms)
2016-12-28T01:01:25.554749+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-12-28T01:01:25.554669 #4]  INFO -- : [6a2e2c9e-b81e-4ad4-91fc-465c54f339f4] Completed 200 OK in 526ms (Views: 13.7ms | ActiveRecord: 21.7ms)
2016-12-28T01:01:25.569551+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/?hmac=df343ac1be8d47fc346c85012e46870a3d1d2c7d593259d6a7e5e2e4be2a60d6&protocol=https%3A%2F%2F&shop=gels-store.myshopify.com&timestamp=1482886883" host=angelstore.herokuapp.com request_id=6a2e2c9e-b81e-4ad4-91fc-465c54f339f4 fwd="222.127.11.170" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=544ms status=200 bytes=3372
2016-12-28T01:01:29.415828+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-12-28T01:01:29.415735 #4]  INFO -- : [67b7923f-112d-499e-8ee4-76afe17220ab] Started GET "/home/show.7867909648" for 222.127.11.170 at 2016-12-28 01:01:29 +0000
2016-12-28T01:01:29.417488+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-12-28T01:01:29.417421 #4]  INFO -- : [67b7923f-112d-499e-8ee4-76afe17220ab] Processing by HomeController#show as
2016-12-28T01:01:29.426318+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2016-12-28T01:01:29.426226 #4] DEBUG -- : [67b7923f-112d-499e-8ee4-76afe17220ab]   Shop Load (2.6ms)  SELECT  "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2016-12-28T01:01:29.601847+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-12-28T01:01:29.601755 #4]  INFO -- : [67b7923f-112d-499e-8ee4-76afe17220ab] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 184ms (ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)
2016-12-28T01:01:29.603340+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-12-28T01:01:29.603284 #4] FATAL -- : [67b7923f-112d-499e-8ee4-76afe17220ab]
2016-12-28T01:01:29.603452+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-12-28T01:01:29.603370 #4] FATAL -- : [67b7923f-112d-499e-8ee4-76afe17220ab] ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound (Failed.  Response code = 404.  Response message = Not Found.):
2016-12-28T01:01:29.603537+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-12-28T01:01:29.603474 #4] FATAL -- : [67b7923f-112d-499e-8ee4-76afe17220ab]
2016-12-28T01:01:29.603653+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-12-28T01:01:29.603603 #4] FATAL -- : [67b7923f-112d-499e-8ee4-76afe17220ab] app/controllers/home_controller.rb:13:in `show'
2016-12-28T01:01:29.617184+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/home/show.7867909648" host=angelstore.herokuapp.com request_id=67b7923f-112d-499e-8ee4-76afe17220ab fwd="222.127.11.170" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=191ms status=500 bytes=1669
2016-12-28T01:17:34.584890+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-12-28T01:17:34.584834 #4]  INFO -- : [a590ebad-6c05-440b-b645-603cd8bfc079] Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2016-12-28T01:17:34.582622+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-12-28T01:17:34.582517 #4]  INFO -- : [a590ebad-6c05-440b-b645-603cd8bfc079] Started GET "/?hmac=0357daa86308275954f0df7389e33ab87eb55cdb9091a99466912e12cd5a523f&protocol=https%3A%2F%2F&shop=gels-store.myshopify.com&timestamp=1482887853" for 222.127.11.170 at 2016-12-28 01:17:34 +0000
2016-12-28T01:17:34.589609+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2016-12-28T01:17:34.589524 #4] DEBUG -- : [a590ebad-6c05-440b-b645-603cd8bfc079]   Shop Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2016-12-28T01:17:34.585031+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-12-28T01:17:34.584976 #4]  INFO -- : [a590ebad-6c05-440b-b645-603cd8bfc079]   Parameters: {"hmac"=>"0357daa86308275954f0df7389e33ab87eb55cdb9091a99466912e12cd5a523f", "protocol"=>"https://", "shop"=>"gels-store.myshopify.com", "timestamp"=>"1482887853"}
2016-12-28T01:17:35.028248+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/?hmac=0357daa86308275954f0df7389e33ab87eb55cdb9091a99466912e12cd5a523f&protocol=https%3A%2F%2F&shop=gels-store.myshopify.com&timestamp=1482887853" host=angelstore.herokuapp.com request_id=a590ebad-6c05-440b-b645-603cd8bfc079 fwd="222.127.11.170" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=441ms status=200 bytes=3372
2016-12-28T01:17:35.008395+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-12-28T01:17:35.008284 #4]  INFO -- : [a590ebad-6c05-440b-b645-603cd8bfc079]   Rendering home/index.html.erb within layouts/embedded_app
2016-12-28T01:17:35.011436+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-12-28T01:17:35.011355 #4]  INFO -- : [a590ebad-6c05-440b-b645-603cd8bfc079]   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/embedded_app (2.7ms)
2016-12-28T01:17:35.013398+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-12-28T01:17:35.013331 #4]  INFO -- : [a590ebad-6c05-440b-b645-603cd8bfc079]   Rendered layouts/_flash_messages.html.erb (0.3ms)
2016-12-28T01:17:35.014512+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-12-28T01:17:35.014462 #4]  INFO -- : [a590ebad-6c05-440b-b645-603cd8bfc079] Completed 200 OK in 429ms (Views: 6.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
2016-12-28T01:49:25.658231+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-12-28T01:49:25.658126 #4]  INFO -- : [793b1499-9bcb-4150-ba39-2973ac73500c] Started GET "/?hmac=9da8f8d814183cb0ac7802880e8848e4bce51c2d864406998d7b8b3f5bc95022&protocol=https%3A%2F%2F&shop=gels-store.myshopify.com&timestamp=1482889764" for 222.127.11.170 at 2016-12-28 01:49:25 +0000
2016-12-28T01:49:25.659753+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-12-28T01:49:25.659678 #4]  INFO -- : [793b1499-9bcb-4150-ba39-2973ac73500c] Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2016-12-28T01:49:25.659835+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-12-28T01:49:25.659776 #4]  INFO -- : [793b1499-9bcb-4150-ba39-2973ac73500c]   Parameters: {"hmac"=>"9da8f8d814183cb0ac7802880e8848e4bce51c2d864406998d7b8b3f5bc95022", "protocol"=>"https://", "shop"=>"gels-store.myshopify.com", "timestamp"=>"1482889764"}
2016-12-28T01:49:25.671459+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2016-12-28T01:49:25.671165 #4] DEBUG -- : [793b1499-9bcb-4150-ba39-2973ac73500c]   Shop Load (5.5ms)  SELECT  "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2016-12-28T01:49:26.119086+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/?hmac=9da8f8d814183cb0ac7802880e8848e4bce51c2d864406998d7b8b3f5bc95022&protocol=https%3A%2F%2F&shop=gels-store.myshopify.com&timestamp=1482889764" host=angelstore.herokuapp.com request_id=793b1499-9bcb-4150-ba39-2973ac73500c fwd="222.127.11.170" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=465ms status=200 bytes=3372
2016-12-28T01:49:26.107927+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-12-28T01:49:26.107802 #4]  INFO -- : [793b1499-9bcb-4150-ba39-2973ac73500c]   Rendering home/index.html.erb within layouts/embedded_app
2016-12-28T01:49:26.109971+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-12-28T01:49:26.109899 #4]  INFO -- : [793b1499-9bcb-4150-ba39-2973ac73500c]   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/embedded_app (1.9ms)
2016-12-28T01:49:26.111276+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-12-28T01:49:26.111176 #4]  INFO -- : [793b1499-9bcb-4150-ba39-2973ac73500c]   Rendered layouts/_flash_messages.html.erb (0.2ms)
2016-12-28T01:49:26.111884+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-12-28T01:49:26.111817 #4]  INFO -- : [793b1499-9bcb-4150-ba39-2973ac73500c] Completed 200 OK in 452ms (Views: 4.2ms | ActiveRecord: 5.5ms)
2016-12-28T01:49:26.522691+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-cbbb5732d70d7094ddba7a7ba5746b6e55093adf1a04b07303a293e1e378e91a.js" host=angelstore.herokuapp.com request_id=e239ea0c-3fc5-4af6-9262-85765448fd2e fwd="222.127.11.170" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=304 bytes=48
2016-12-28T01:49:35.375345+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-12-28T01:49:35.375220 #4]  INFO -- : [985ea4ca-52de-405d-9dd2-9811f0c0455b] Started GET "/home/show.7867909648" for 222.127.11.170 at 2016-12-28 01:49:35 +0000
2016-12-28T01:49:35.376624+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-12-28T01:49:35.376568 #4]  INFO -- : [985ea4ca-52de-405d-9dd2-9811f0c0455b] Processing by HomeController#show as
2016-12-28T01:49:35.380593+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2016-12-28T01:49:35.380522 #4] DEBUG -- : [985ea4ca-52de-405d-9dd2-9811f0c0455b]   Shop Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2016-12-28T01:49:35.542679+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-12-28T01:49:35.542574 #4]  INFO -- : [985ea4ca-52de-405d-9dd2-9811f0c0455b] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 166ms (ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
2016-12-28T01:49:35.544843+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-12-28T01:49:35.544775 #4] FATAL -- : [985ea4ca-52de-405d-9dd2-9811f0c0455b]
2016-12-28T01:49:35.544921+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-12-28T01:49:35.544862 #4] FATAL -- : [985ea4ca-52de-405d-9dd2-9811f0c0455b] ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound (Failed.  Response code = 404.  Response message = Not Found.):
2016-12-28T01:49:35.544984+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-12-28T01:49:35.544930 #4] FATAL -- : [985ea4ca-52de-405d-9dd2-9811f0c0455b]
2016-12-28T01:49:35.545049+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-12-28T01:49:35.544997 #4] FATAL -- : [985ea4ca-52de-405d-9dd2-9811f0c0455b] app/controllers/home_controller.rb:13:in `show'
2016-12-28T01:49:35.551115+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/home/show.7867909648" host=angelstore.herokuapp.com request_id=985ea4ca-52de-405d-9dd2-9811f0c0455b fwd="222.127.11.170" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=174ms status=500 bytes=1669
```

Comment: what does the error say?  Could you post the error output or screenshot?

Comment: @RockwellRice sorry bout that, I've just added the logs

Comment: It looks like it is looking for a shop using the id, but it seems from your description that id is meant for a product, is that correct? Can you share the link to the tutorial?

Comment: @RockwellRice this is the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DB48N8rRHFw ...i added and changed some codes